# Error : Need to specify class name in environment or system property

Tags: jakarta-ee, jndi

I'm new in development of Java EE applications and I'm really confused about this. I've found so many answers but I can't resolve my problem.

This is the error:

> javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

And this is my code :

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Auto_2G> auto2 = new ArrayList<Auto_2G>();
        GestionCellRef2GRemote t = null;
        Context contxt=null ;
        //GestionCellRefDualmodeRemote p = null;
        //Auto_Dualmode autodualmode = new Auto_Dualmode();
        FileInputStream file=null;
        HSSFWorkbook classeur=null ;
        HSSFSheet feuille=null;
        Row roww=null;

        try {
            try {
                contxt = new InitialContext();
            } catch(NamingException e) {

            }
            t = (GestionCellRef2GRemote) contxt.lookup("/webpfe/GestionCellRef2G!tn.orange.pfe.services.GestionCellRef2GR emote");
            file= new FileInputStream(new File("test.xls"));
            classeur = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
            feuille = classeur.getSheetAt(0);
            int i=1;

            while(roww!=null) {
                roww=feuille.getRow(i);

                for (Auto_2G auto2g:auto2) {
                    auto2g.setBSC_Name(roww.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
                    auto2g.setBTS_NAME(roww.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
                    auto2g.setCELL_NAME(roww.getCell(4).getStringCellValue());

                    t.ajout2G(auto2g);
                }
                i++;
            }
            file.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("erreur"+e);
        }

        for(Auto_2G auto2g:auto2){
        System.out.println(auto2g.getId());
    }
```

And this is my *JNDI.properties* file:

```
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.ejb.client.naming
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=http-remoting://localhost:8181
jboss.naming.client.ejb.context=true
jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT=false
```

---

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to create remoting connection [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: XNIO001001: No XNIO provider found]
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ClientUtil.namingException(ClientUtil.java:51)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:152)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at tn.orange.pfe.test.Test.main(Test.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: XNIO001001: No XNIO provider found
    at org.xnio.Xnio.doGetInstance(Xnio.java:226)
    at org.xnio.Xnio.getInstance(Xnio.java:192)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.EndpointCache.get(EndpointCache.java:47)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.createEndpoint(InitialContextFactory.java:226)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getOrCreateEndpoint(InitialContextFactory.java:207)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getOrCreateNamingStore(InitialContextFactory.java:170)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:146)
    ... 5 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at tn.orange.pfe.test.Test.main(Test.java:46)
erreurjava.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: You need to load your *jndi.properties* and pass it to your `InitialContext`. Take a look at *Constructing a JNDI Context* and *The JNDI Environment* mentioned [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14012/jndi.htm).

Comment: Thank u, i will see it ^^

Comment: @MOhamed I can think of two reasons either JNDI.properties is not in the classpath or it should be renamed to jndi.properties (lowercase). But then, as a quick check to see if it is a problem with this properties file or not, you can set these properties in a `Properties` object like `Properties prop = new Properties(); 
prop.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8181"); and so on` etc and pass it to InitialContext as `Context context = new InitialContext(prop);`

Comment: After reading i see that the file jndi.properties is setting in the classpath and it is already loaded :/ maybe i didnt understand very well the tuto, can u help me more plz :/ @aribeiro

Comment: Hi Madhusudana first of all thanks, and i got now other problem after doing what u say 
 [erreurjava.lang.NullPointerException]
@MadhusudanaReddySunnapu

Comment: @MOhamed NPEs are easier to fix. Can you post the exception stacktrace or check the line where you are getting NPE?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu thats the problem cuz i got source not found when i try to check the line -_-

Comment: @MOhamed Can you post the stacktrace and the updated code? By the way, are you getting this error before or after `contxt.looup(...)` method? I see an empty space in the lookup method `lRef2GR emote` between `R` and `e`, is that ok? Similarly you code say `Row roww=null` and in the while loop(roww !=null), it will be never pass this loop. should it be `do..while` instead?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu there is no space in my code that was a typo

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu and this is all the stacktrace: 
#erreurjava.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @MOhamed Instead of `System.out.println("erreur"+e);` do a `e.printStackTrace()` that will help you pinpoint the NPE location? By the way, don't add the updated code as answer. In the same question above, add it as UPDATED code.

Comment: @MOhamed Look at the exception `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory` You don't have that necessary jar file in your classpath. By the way, don't add the updated code as answer. In the same question above, add it as UPDATED code.

Comment: ok i will see it thanks Madhusudana Reddy Sunnapu ^^

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu look at the new updates i go back to the first problem and i get more when i have added the jar files -_-

Answer (score 0):

This is the code after the update :

```
  public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Auto_2G> auto2 = new ArrayList<Auto_2G>();
        GestionCellRef2GRemote t = null;
        Context contxt=null ;
        //GestionCellRefDualmodeRemote p = null;
        //Auto_Dualmode autodualmode = new Auto_Dualmode();
        FileInputStream file=null;
        HSSFWorkbook classeur=null ;
        HSSFSheet feuille=null;
        Row roww=null;
        Properties prop = new Properties(); 
        prop.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8181");
         prop.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
         prop.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
try {

    try{
        contxt = new InitialContext(prop);
    }
    catch (NamingException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}      

    t = (GestionCellRef2GRemote) contxt.lookup("/GestionCellRef2G!tn.orange.pfe.services.GestionCellRef2GRemote");
    file= new FileInputStream(new File("test.xls"));
    classeur = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
 feuille = classeur.getSheetAt(0);
 int i=1;

 while(roww!=null){
         roww=feuille.getRow(i);
         for(Auto_2G auto2g:auto2){
    auto2g.setBSC_Name(roww.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
    auto2g.setBTS_NAME(roww.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
    auto2g.setCELL_NAME(roww.getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
    auto2g.setLAC(Long.parseLong(roww.getCell(10).getStringCellValue()));
    auto2g.setCell_CI(Long.parseLong(roww.getCell(11).getStringCellValue()));
    auto2g.setBCC(Integer.parseInt(roww.getCell(12).getStringCellValue()));
    auto2g.setNCC(Integer.parseInt(roww.getCell(13).getStringCellValue()));
    auto2g.setBand(roww.getCell(14).getStringCellValue());
    auto2g.setBCCH(Long.parseLong(roww.getCell(15).getStringCellValue()));
    //String a =(Integer.parseInt(roww.getCell(12).getStringCellValue()))*10+roww.getCell(13).getStringCellValue();
    //int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
    //auto2g.setBSIC_dec(b);
    //String y=(Integer.parseInt(roww.getCell(13).getStringCellValue()))*8+roww.getCell(12).getStringCellValue();
//  int x= Integer.parseInt(y);
    //auto2g.setBSIC_oct( x);
    auto2g.setNumber_of_2G_Neighbor_Cell_for_GSM_Cell(Integer.parseInt(roww.getCell(28).getStringCellValue()));
    auto2g.setNumber_of_3G_Neighbor_Cell_for_GSM_Cell(Integer.parseInt(roww.getCell(29).getStringCellValue()));
    auto2g.setNumber_of_GSM_TRX(Integer.parseInt(roww.getCell(17).getStringCellValue()));
    auto2g.setBramwidth(65);
    auto2g.setNo_BCCH_Freq_list(Float.parseFloat(roww.getCell(16).getStringCellValue()));
    t.ajout2G(auto2g);
         }

    i++;

    }


    file.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("erreur"+e);
e.printStackTrace();
}


for(Auto_2G auto2g:auto2){
    System.out.println(auto2g.getId());
}

            // Créer un objet classuer



            // Lire la première feuille de ce classuer


            // Créer un Itérateur sur la feuille
            //Iterator<Row> rowIterator = feuille.iterator();



        // insertion en BD

        // p.ajoutDm(autodualmode);

    }

}
```

Comment: Your updated code still reads `contxt = new InitialContext();`. It should be `contxt = new InitialContext(prop);`

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu i resolve it and if u know  what the problem was u will kill me :p

Comment: Glad that you resolved it. But what was the problem, i guess it must be a silly mistake? :)

Comment: in the provider url"  "http-remoting://localhost:8181" i just replaced it by "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:18181" and all the errors are gone :p :D im feeling so noob --'

Comment: That's cool. I couldn't even guess that could be a problem. Anyways,finally it could not escape from you. Good catch. ;-)

Comment: yeah its a problem and i dont know why -_- the interface of the server cant be open with the dns (Localhost).... finally "Merci beaucoup" for helping ^^ see u in other questions :p